# Passar match.params para dentro de outro componente

Tags: react, react-router

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho um componente de step e dentro desse componente tenho outro componente chamado form que renderiza um dos passos do step.

Pois bem, no step eu consigo obter o id passado com o código `this.props.match.params.id` só que nesse step eu tenho outro componente chamado form e nesse form eu perco a referência do id passado para o step.

Eu sei que poderia mudar na rota para que chamasse direto o form e assim eu teria o id, mas preciso que seja renderizado o setp e dentro dele o form.

Como faço pra passar o id do step para o form?

Minha rota está assim:

```
<Route path="/stepAluno/(new|edit)/:id?" component={StepAluno} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

depois de obter o id pelo `match.params`, passei o id via `props` para o componente form.